# PHP/MySQL: Always show "No data" even though the data is exist at database table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

currently I create a system with a 'search' function. At the input text, if I enter the correct badge id, it will display all the staff data, but if enter wrong data, it will alert 'No Data'. Below is the code:

```
<?php

require_once "../../config/configPDO.php";
require_once "../../config/check.php";
$team =  $_SESSION['team'];

$badgeid = '';
$fullname = '';
$roles_id = '';

function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();

    $posts[0] = $_POST['badgeid'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['fullname'];
    $posts[4] = $_POST['roles_id'];

    return $posts;
}

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    if(empty($data[0]))
    {
      echo "
      <script>alert('Please enter badge id')</script>";
    }  else {

        $searchStmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND roles_id = "4"');
        $searchStmt->execute(array(
                    ':badgeid'=> $data[0]
        ));

        if($searchStmt)
        {
            $user = $searchStmt->fetch();
            if(empty($user))
            {
              echo "
              <script>alert('No data')</script>";
            }

            $badgeid = $user[0];
            $fullname = $user[3];
            $roles_id = $user[4];
        }

    }
}
```

From the query above, when the roles_id = '4', and I enter the correct badge id, it will display all the staff data.

But if I entered the correct badge id, but the roles_id at the database is 5, it also will display alert 'No data'.

Now, how I want to make sure that, if I entered correct badge id but the roles id is not equal to 4, it will alert 'Staff is eligible'

Can anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: in the query `WHERE badgeid = :badgeid`  ":badgeid" is ambiguous try outputing the last query and see if it produces any result in DB

Comment: @ClainDsilva it's a parameter, bound in the next line. How is it ambiguous?

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly, and show what you've done to try and solve it. You say "if I enter the correct badge id, it will display all the staff data, but if enter wrong data, it will alert 'No Data'" which is exactly what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @miken32 what I mean is try to print the generated query and execute it in the database terminal to see if the database returns any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query to fetch user data when `roles_id` is either 4 or 5, and then check the value fetched in the query. If it is 5, `Staff is eligible` is alerted, otherwise the values from the fetch are assigned as you do currently:

```
$searchStmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND roles_id IN (4, 5)');
$searchStmt->execute(array(
                ':badgeid'=> $data[0]
));

if($searchStmt) {
    $user = $searchStmt->fetch();
    if(empty($user)) {
        echo "<script>alert('No data')</script>";
    }
    elseif ($user[4] == 5) {
        echo "<script>alert('Staff is eligible')</script>";
    }
    else {
        $badgeid = $user[0];
        $fullname = $user[3];
        $roles_id = $user[4];
    }
}
```

Note that using associative keys for fetching data from a table is much safer. If the table was modified with an extra column between the first and the fourth columns, your code would stop working.

Comment: nice. But let say if I want to make roles_id is not equal to 4, alert 'Staff is eligible' ? because the answer you give is just only for roles id equal to 5. Can u show me?

Comment: @pundek to do that, you would remove the condition on `roles_id` in the query, and change `$user[4] == 5` to `$user[4] != 4`